# Use of $$ in the make file?

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following structure

```
home
|-- Makefile
|-- H1
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- h1.c
|-- H2
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- h2.c
|-- main.c
```

**H1/Makefile**

```
h1.o:h1.c
        gcc -c h1.c
```

**H2/Makefile**

```
h2.o:h2.c
        gcc -c h2.c
```

**home/Makefile**

```
DIR = h1 h2
main.out:main.o
        for i in $(DIR);\
        do (cd $$i; make);\ //1.why () used here to encolose 2 commands and $$ before the i
        done
        gcc -o main.out main.o ./h1/h1.o ./h1/h1.o

main.o:main.c
        gcc -c main.c
```

The above works fine and giving me the out file but,i have doubt that is this the efficient way of doing this compilation or any other way to do this.

My questions are mentioned on the comments of the code and also follows

```
I have tried like 
do(cd $i;make;)//this showing error
also do(cd $$i;)make;//this also sowing error
```

,kindly give me some idea.what is going here.
I gone through some books,I found that $$ means the current process Id ,but what is the use of this here before the i.

Also what is the mening of using `()`,to enclose two commands[`cd` and `make`].

Kindly give me some answer for my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

`make` expands all *make-variables* (like `$(CFLAGS)` or `$@`) in the action of a rule, then uses the shell to execute it. And `$$` is expanded as `$`. So the shell sees `$i` inside its `for` loop. If you only wrote `$i` in the rule, it would be expanded (as `$(i)` would be) to empty by `make` before invoking the shell (because *make* don't have any bound `i` *make-variable*).

Use [GNU remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), as `remake -x` to undestand what is happenning.

BTW, I believe your `Makefile` is wrong: `(cd $$i; make)` should be `$(MAKE) -C $$i` 
(because GNU *make* processes quite specially `$(MAKE)`, e.g. when you start a `make -j 2`)

Answer (score 1):

**1:** As @BasileStarynkevitch says, Make expands this:

```
for i in $(DIR); do (cd $$i; make); done
```

into this:

```
for i in h1 h2; do (cd $i; make); done
```

and passes it to the shell.

<strike>**2:** The parentheses are not necessary. This works just as well:</strike>

```
for i in $(DIR); do cd $$i; make; done
```

[I was wrong about this point, as Virgile pointed out.]

**3:** As @BasileStarynkevitch says, `$(MAKE) -C $$i` is better than `cd $$i; make`.

**4:** You can do without the loop altogether (and thereby handle the dependencies correctly):

```
h1/h1.o: h1/h1.c
    $(MAKE) -C h1

h2/h2.o: h2/h2.c
    $(MAKE) -C h2

main.out:main.o h1/h2.o h1/h2.o
    gcc -o main.out main.o ./h1/h1.o ./h2/h2.o
```

**5:** You can do without the recursion altogether:

```
h1/h1.o: h1/h1.c
    gcc -c h1/h1.c -o h1/h1.o

h2/h2.o: h2/h2.c
    gcc -c h2/h2.c -o h2/h2.o
```

**5:** You can use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to make your rules cleaner:

```
h1/h1.o: h1/h1.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

h2/h2.o: h2/h2.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

main.out:main.o h1/h2.o h1/h2.o
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

You can simplify even more, but for such a simple makefile it isn't worthwhile.

Comment: I beg to differ on 2. With the parentheses, `(cd $i; make)` is executed in a subshell (which in particular means that `cd` doesn't affect the main shell). If you omit them, this gets executed directly by the main shell, so that you stay in `h1` at the end of the first step (of course this won't happen with `$(MAKE) -C h1` which is yet another reason to use that).

Comment: @Virgile: you're absolutely right, thank you. I should have tested more carefully.